# How to Authenticate in Odata V4 Remote Service

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need to connect to an SL server, which has authentication, but I do not know how to specify the User and Password properties in the oData V4 dataSources.

```
"dataSources": {
    "mainService": {
        "uri": "https://miserver.com:50000/b1s/v2/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
            "odataVersion": "4.0",
            "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
    }
};
```

[This is oDATA V2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DFei.png)
 The user and password properties pass as parameters to authenticate in the Service, but in V4 I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, this is not the right way to pass authentication information to the server as it is not secure.

However, this might help you:
In the header, you can pass the username and password.

```js
"models":{  
   "":{  
      "dataSource":"mainService",
      "settings":{  
         "defaultBindingMode":"TwoWay",
         "defaultCountMode":"Inline",
         "refreshAfterChange":false,
         "headers":{  
            "myHeader1":"value1",
            "myHeader2":"value2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i have this error Uncaught Error: Unsupported parameter: defaultBindingMode, headers, etc.. im usng oData V4